# How to show loading when a form is being submitting to the database using Jquery

Tags: jquery, .post

I am trying to show the loading while the form is being submitting to the database but no luck. 
The loading show after the form submitted.

I am using Jquery to submit the form here is the it is.

```
$("form#data").on('submit',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.loading').show(); // show loading while form submit to database.

        var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);

        $.ajax({
            url: 'includes/new_post.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: formData,
            async: false,
            success: function (data) {
                $('.note').html(data);
                $('.loading').hide(); // hide loading after form submitted.
            },
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false

        });

        return false;
    });
```

Please help with this.

Comment: The problem is entirely caused by `async: false` as it blocks the UI from updating while the request is in process. Remove that property and your code will work

Comment: Thanks i really appreciate it. works perfect

Answer (score 0):

For this try to use beforeSend function, and also complete function. Hope my suggestion will help you.

```
    $("form#data").on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);

    $.ajax({
        url: 'includes/new_post.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        async: false,
        beforeSend: function() {
            $('.loading').show(); // show loading while form submit to database.
        },
        success: function(data) {
            $('.note').html(data);

        },
        complete: function() {
            $('.loading').hide(); // hide loading after form submitted.
        },
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false

    });

    return false;
});
```